# how to create alias in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, alias

I want to create an alias like this:

```
alias myc++testenv='ssh myserver "cd /home/workdir/workspacetest/;";'
```

Is there an error, because it is not working.

Gruß, Andre

Comment: `+` is not allowed in alias names

Comment: What error are you getting? `bash` allows `+` in the name of an alias. (Try `alias myc++testenv="echo hello"`.) I suspect the issue is that you expect an interactive shell on `myserver` to still be running after it executes the `cd` remotely.

Comment: I tried: ssh myserver "hostname" -> this command gives back "myserver", but it stays on the local machine, what I did not expected. I thougt, it would stay on myserver.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the + symbol then bash interprets that as an operation.